# Using SQL to calculate average number of customers

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

[image]

Please see above for the data structure. I am trying to write an SQL query to get the average number of customers for each session

My attempt:

```
select avg(A.NumberCustomer)
from(
select SessionName, count(distinct customers.Idcustomer) as NumberCustomer, 
from customers, enrollments, sessions
where customers.Idcustomer=enrollments.Idcustomer and enrollments.Idsession=sessions.Idsession
group by sessions.SessionName
) A
```

But I seem to get an error on the from customers, enrollments, sessions line
Not sure about this, any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Add schema structure and some dump data

Comment: That's a lovely diagram but more usefull would have been a schema and sample data as @NiranjanKumar has mentioned

Comment: what's the error message exactly? it's more helpful coming directly from the database :) keep trying!

Comment: Your error, as pointed out in @danihp's answer, is the extra comma.  You actually didn't need to join to the sessions table.  You could have grouped by enrollments.IDsession.  When you are dealing with large amounts of data, little things like this affect performance.

Answer (score 3):

You have and extra comma that you should to delete:

```
select avg(A.NumberCustomer)
from(
select SessionName, 
       count(distinct customers.Idcustomer) as NumberCustomer, #<--- here
from customers, enrollments, sessions
where customers.Idcustomer=enrollments.Idcustomer 
  and enrollments.Idsession=sessions.Idsession
group by sessions.SessionName
) A
```

By the way, I suggest to you to move to SQL'99 join syntax for readability reasons:

```
SELECT 
    avg(A.NumberCustomer)
FROM (
   select 
      SessionName, 
      count(distinct customers.Idcustomer) as NumberCustomer
   from customers 
   inner join enrollments
      on customers.Idcustomer=enrollments.Idcustomer 
   inner join sessions
      on enrollments.Idsession=sessions.Idsession
   group by sessions.SessionName
) A
```

Also, nice diagram on question and remember to include your error message next time.

Comment: Thanks this gets it working - just not sure if it's actually producing what I want it to do, i.e.  get the average no. of customers in each session

Comment: You are welcome. I answered your both questions: fixed error and SQL to to calculate average number of customers. Fi you have new requirements be free to open a new question. Don't forget to include sample data and expected one. Good luck man!

Comment: @user33484 according to your schema every session has a -one- number of customers, which means no average here. do you mean you want the average number of the customer in ALL sessions , e.g (session1-> 3 customers) , (session2 -> 5 customers) , (session3 -> 7 customers) . and there avg is avg(3,5,7) = 5 ?

Comment: @danihp I'm not the one who asked the question  :))

Comment: @user56489870, srr, post comment behind OP question, not under my answer : )

Answer (score 2):

For the average number of customers in each session, you should be able to use just the enrollments table.  The average would be the number of enrollments divided by the number of sessions:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct idSession)
from enrollments e;
```

This makes the following assumptions:

- All sessions have at least one customer (your original query had this assumption as well).
- No customer signs up multiple times for the same session.